# What are the differences between mapcat in Clojure and flatMap in Scala in terms of what they operate on?

Tags: scala, clojure

I understand the equivalent to `flatMap` in Scala is [`mapcat`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/mapcat) in Clojure.

I have an inkling that `mapcat` in clojure only works with sequences, unlike `flatMap` in Scala which is more flexible.

My question is - what are the differences between `mapcat` in Clojure and `flatMap` in Scala in terms of what they operate on?

Assumptions:

- I understand that Scala has a rich type system and Clojure has optional typing - I'm interested to know if the is a limitation in the parameters that mapcat accepts that make it only have a subset of `flatMap`s functionality.

Comment: What do you think a collection means in clojure? As it stands the "only works on collections" statement seems extremely odd, as I could not imagine what mapcat (or map even) would mean on something that cannot be treated as containing multiple values. Also map works on things like String that are not considered clojure collections, as well as all the collection types. Clojure is not optionally typed - static type checking is optional (and not in the core language) but there is no such thing as an untyped value in clojure.

Comment: Agree re 'collections' in Clojure - it was an answer here and I was trying to find out more about what was meant in case there was something I had missed: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/220150/13382

Comment: Any object can implement ISeq and will then be a target for mapcat. Period. His assertion that mapcat does not use protocols is flat out 100% wrong. mapcat is implemented in terms of concat and map, both call seq on their args. seq works on anything that implements ISeq (with special cases for Java native objects that do not implement ISeq).

Comment: If I took a superficial glance at Scala, I am sure I could make similarly ignorant claims based on unfounded assumptions that Scala should behave like clojure does.

Comment: @noisesmith From http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/mapcat: "Thus function f should return a collection."

Comment: @noisesmith "I could not imagine what mapcat (or map even) would mean on something that cannot be treated as containing multiple values" Precisely. It's a part of the meaning of `mapcat` and `map` in Clojure, but it isn't a part of the meaning of `flatMap` and `map` in Scala. I am _not_ saying that Clojure does anything wrong, worse than Scala, that it should have one name for these operations just because Scala does, etc.

Comment: The distinction here may be that in clojure we are fond of the Sequence abstraction, so even things like Strings, Records or an abstraction over a repeated operation like iterate are all usable as sequences. To say something in clojure "only works on collections" is to my eye like saying something in forth "only works on machine dependent byte values". It's the lingua franca that we turn everything into if we want to do anything interesting to it (even our code, thanks to homoiconicity).

Comment: I could be missing some subtlety about the Scala semantics to be sure. I worry that I am acting like a "blub" programmer here, arguing about a feature I don't yet understand.

Comment: thanks noisesmith - I have updated the question re collections

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback @noisesmith - could you provide a comment on @ Alexy's answer below as to whether you think it is valid or has an opportunity for improvement?

Comment: @noisesmith "even things like Strings, Records or an abstraction over a repeated operation like iterate are all usable as sequences ... It's the lingua franca that we turn everything into if we want to do anything interesting to it" What about e.g. futures or core.async channels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real difference is that flatMap is polymorphic on the type, and mapcat isn't. So any type can decide to provide a "flatMap" like behaviour. That's how you get things like Futures being flatMapable.

In Clojure, mapcat is specific to the seqable type. Any seqable can be coerced into a sequence, and all sequence can be mapped and concatenated. The mapcat implementation will check if the input is seqable, if so, it will call seq on it to coerce it to a sequence, and then it will map and cat that sequence and give you back a sequence. You don't get back a result of the original type.

In Scala, if you implement IterableLike trait (I think that's the right interface), you get the default flatMap implementation which is a bit like the Clojure one minus the coercion to sequence. But, many types also provide a custom implementation of flatMap, making it generic in that way.

Answer (score 5):

I know a little about Scala but it seems to me flatMap is the Scala bind function in a monad and mapcat is a possible implementation of the bind function for the sequence monad in Clojure. So they are the same for sequences.

But Scala for example has a flatMap function for Futures: it takes a future and a mapping function and returns a future that will complete after input future completes. This operation doesn't seem to be a simple mapcat in Clojure. It may be realized this way instead

```
(defn flat-map [f mv] (mapcat (fn [v] (future (f @v))) mv))
```

So, no. They are not the same, neither in terms of what they operate on. In Scala flatMap is the common name for different functions and for example Futures' flatMap coordinates input and output futures. A simple mapcat in Clojure won't work because it won't return a future.

Comment: "flatMap is the bind function in List monad" No, `flatMap` is the common Scala name for all `bind` functions.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thank you, I edited my answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 4):

They seem very similar and appear to work on the same kind of things. From looking at the documentation and [examples](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/collection-scala-flatmap-examples-map-flatten) I can't see a functional difference.

`mapcat` works on sequences, and just about every clojure data type can be a sequence. If you pass something that is not already a `seq` to `mapcat` it will call seq on it automatically, so **in practice you can pass just about all clojure values to mapcat**. If you want to iterate over a tree you would need to call `prewalk` or `postwalk` to specify the traversal order.

Comment: "From looking at the documentation and examples I can't see a functional difference." See these examples instead: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Answer (score 4):

In the standard Scala library: [`Responder`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Responder), [`Future`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future), [`Parser`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers%24Parser), [`ControlContext`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.continuations.ControlContext). None of them are sequences or particularly sequence-like. There is also a slight variation in [`ParseResult`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers%24ParseResult).